# Error importing static files from S3 Bucket Django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried uploading my static and media files onto AWS S3 bucket but, the css is not being rendered.

`settings.py`

```
AWS_HEADERS = {  # see http://developer.yahoo.com/performance /rules.html#expires
    'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2099 20:00:00 GMT',
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=94608000',
}

AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = '*'
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = '*'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = '*'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = '%s.s3.amazonaws.com' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/" % AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
STATIC_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, STATICFILES_LOCATION)
MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = "https://%s/%s/" % (AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN, MEDIAFILES_LOCATION)
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
```

And when I try to access the css file through its source I get the following message -

```
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>BD606AFA0AF488B7</RequestId>
<HostId>2aZOfc5qdORtn2VhfDQsJ2gZHPoYBeBV9ciAdOnk+wGuK7azaWngXwfv+rEy1XLMFOrOgs+qDpI= </HostId>
</Error>
```

Comment: Could you include the line in your template where you link to the CSS? Include the line showing what the link is displayed as in the HTML source as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry was making a silly mistake. The root of the static folders was not specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` so `collectstatic` command couldn't collect those files.